# source command not detecting the file in Linux bash

Tags: bash

Here is an excerpt from my Bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check SPEED parameter validity
if [ "$4" = "SPEED" ] 
then
    source ${SIM_DIR}/setEnv.sh speed
elif [ "$4" = "NORMAL" ]
then
    pushd ${SIM_DIR}/scripts
    source setEnv
else
    ERROR "Invalid SPEED|NORMAL parameter ($4)."
    exit 1
fi
```

In command line, I am giving the option as `NORMAL` when I run the script. There is no file called `setEnv.sh` in the `${SIM_DIR}/scripts` location. There is however a file called `setEnv` and its first line is `#!/bin/bash -x`. I get the following error:

```
line 176: source: setEnv: file not found
```

Could anybody kindly point out what is wrong with my script?

Comment: quote the variables: `"${SIM_DIR}"`

Comment: You could try to add a `pwd` command and an `ls` command to your script, to see clearly in which directory it is running and which files really are there.

Comment: shebang `#!/bin/bash -x` has no effect if you source a file.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy - already added pwd and ls and it is exactly in the directory where I want to source setEnv from.

Comment: I copied your script, and (with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`, since the **sh** on my system doesn't have `pushd`), it works as expected on my system. Your problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: The shebang seems to be a big part of the problem. [Bash behaves differently when called as `sh`](/q/26717870/4518341). Plus, [`/bin/sh` is not always Bash](/q/5725296/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

`source` uses `PATH` lookups to find names that do not contain slashes, and your `PATH` (correctly) does not contain `.`, so the current directory is not searched for `setEnv`. Use `source ./setEnv`.

The shebang line is ignored by `source`.

Comment: It's worth adding that this behaviour is specific to POSIX mode, which OP might have done accidentally with the `/bin/sh` shebang. Otherwise Bash would check the current dir after the `PATH`. [Docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html)